# Filtering EntityDataSource with Parameters from a another page

Tags: asp.net, ado.net-entity-data-model, entitydatasource

i have two pages, a Master Page containing a list of all products and a seperate detail pages obviously containing all the details about said product.

In the master page, i have a grid view and by clicking on a link label which for any particular row, should show up the other page (details page) with information based on the id.

*DataNavigateUrlFields: ID
DataNavigateUrlFormatString  : EmployeeFinanceDetailsPage.aspx?id={0}*

This is what i added to the link label, trying to post the id to the details page. by the way, i am using purely entity data source. I have my entity data model configured and working properly.

In my details page, i have a form view configure with a data source as shown below.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=sspEntities" DefaultContainerName="sspEntities"
EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True"
EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="Employee_Financial"
EntityTypeFilter="" Select="" Where="" AutoGenerateWhereClause="True">
WhereParameters> <asp:FormParameter DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="0"
FormField="ID" Name="ID" /> </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

For some reason this page keeps showing up blank, i dont know what i am doing wrong. i even tried removing AutoGenerateWhereClause but i still got the same result. what am i doing wrong? thanks for your advice in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a [`FormParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formparameter.aspx), but passing the ID in the query-string. Try a [`QueryStringParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx) instead.

```
<WhereParameters>
   <asp:QueryStringParameter 
      DbType="Int32" 
      DefaultValue="0"
      QueryStringField="ID" 
      Name="ID" 
   /> 
</WhereParameters>
```